# How to make a specific grid without using !important and only using float

Tags: html, css

I want to make a specific Grid. But it shouldn't be implemented with flexbox, grid or tables. Only float should be used.
I have already the finished code. It should be only changed so that there is **no *!important* in the code** and behave the same way.
If you remove the !important and resize the browser window, then you will see the different behavior.

Here's my code:

```css
/* === General === */

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1328px;
  margin: 3rem auto;
}

/* === Grid === */

.row {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.row .square:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.row .square:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.square {
  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 3);
  float: left;
  max-width: 428px;
}

.square::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.rectangle {
  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 3 * 2 + 30px);
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.rectangle::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 48.28375%;
  background-color: #e95d0e;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .row {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .square {
    float: none;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 370px;
  }
  .rectangle {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 370px;
  }
  .rectangle::before {
    padding-top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section id="topics">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can specify a higher descendant level of your css, like:

```
#topics .square
```

It means `#topics .square` > `.row .square:nth-of-type(*)`, with that said `#topics .square` will override `.row .square:nth-of-type(*)` parameters... So, no need of !important

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

```css
/* === General === */

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1328px;
  margin: 3rem auto;
}


/* === Grid === */
.row {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.row .square:nth-of-type(3) {
 margin-left: 30px;
}

 .row .square:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.square {
  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 3);
  float: left;
  max-width: 428px;
}

.square::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.rectangle {
  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 3 * 2 + 30px);
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.rectangle::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 48.28375%;
  background-color: #e95d0e;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {

  .row {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  #topics .square {
    float: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 370px;
  }

  .rectangle {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 370px;
  }

  .rectangle::before {
    padding-top: 100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="container">

      <section id="topics">


        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="rectangle"></div>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </div>
  
      </section>

    </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it also possible to make the same grid without using crooked percentages and pixel disclosures for the max-width attribute?